# Can Apache ProxyPass retry a request on backend connection failure

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass

I'm using Apache as Reverse Proxy into App server layer - using ProxyPass.

The App Server is single instance (no load balancing).

Periodically (potentially due to some lower level network problem) Apache logs the following error.

```
[Mon Jul 10 12:48:43.491680 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 17325:tid 139862111938304] [client x.x.x.x:21241] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: prod_java, referer: https://my.company.com/app/request
```

and a 503 Service Unavailable response is returned to client.

I am considering setting the following to react quicker to connection failure:

```
ProxyPass /app http://PROD_JAVA:8080/app connectiontimeout=1 retry=0 keepalive=On
```

My question is - in the case of such a failure, is there is there a way to get Apache to retry the request into the backend again - rather than immediately respond back to client?